# Magento 2 Products with Categories not showing under Category Products

Tags: magento2, category, products

I have 10,000 SKUs that are assigned various categories.  I can edit the product and see that it is in a category, however, when I go to that category, and look at the category products, nothing is showing up.  I have tried clearing all the indexes and reindexing.  I am at a loss.  Can someone please point me in the right direction for this one?

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this.  I didn't have the products associated with any web site.  I set this to main/default and they all show now.  A reindex fixed any other issues.